# Only two different ways to identify three boundary circles of a disc with two holes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, quotient-spaces

**Update:** I gave an answer below and I hope it's correct.

---

This question is from [*Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf), Hatcher. Exercise 1.2.13.

**Question:**

For a disk with two holes, it has $3$ boundary circles.

Show there're only two different ways to identify these three circles.

---

**My effort:**

It can be reduced to four cases to identify these $3$ boundary circles, as follows:

[image: Four cases]

Chirality of circles is represented by $+$(clockwise) and $-$(counter clockwise).

Case 1, chirality of circle $1,2,3$ is $(-,-,+)$, fundamental group is $G_1= \langle a,b,c \mid aba^{-1}bcbc^{-1} \rangle$, with abelianization $\mathbb Z_3\oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.

Case 2, chirality of circle $1,2,3$ is $(+,-,+)$, fundamental group is $G_2= \langle a,b,c \mid aba^{-1}bcb^{-1}c^{-1} \rangle$, with abelianization  $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.

Case 3, chirality of circle $1,2,3$ is $(-,-,-)$, fundamental group is $G_3=\langle a,b,c \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}cbc^{-1} \rangle$, with abelianization $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.

Case 4, chirality of circle $1,2,3$ is $(+,-,-)$, fundamental group is $G_4=\langle a,b,c \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}cb^{-1}c^{-1} \rangle$, with abelianization $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.

At first thought, one might think case 1,2 and 4 are equivalent since there're two circles with same orientation and the left one with reversed  orientation.

However, Hatcher in exercise 1.2.12 says fundamental group in case 3 and case 4 are [isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454235), which means case 3 and case 4 are equivalent, so considering the consistence of orientations of three circles doesn't work.

So which of the four cases are equivalent?

If we already know there're only two possibilities, from abelianzation of fundamental groups in four cases, we may deduce case 2,3 and 4 are equivalent. But how can we derive this?

Comment: "show there're only two different ways".to do what?

Comment: @WilliamElliot two different ways to identify (ie map to each other) the 3 boundary circles and thus create a new topological space.

Comment: Alternate approach: instead of drawing the 3 disks in the plane, draw a 'pair of pants' in 3-d. This is fully symmetric in the 3 boundary circles (topologically). Fixing the orientation of one circle immediately reduces to 4 cases. The symmetry should get you the reduction to 2 cases? (need to think/draw more) Your argument then proves that there are at least 2 distinct ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3455473/557551), $G_3\cong G_4$, case 3 and case 4 are equivalent.

In $G_2:=\langle a,b,c \mid aba^{-1}bcb^{-1}c^{-1} \rangle$, replace $a$ by $c'$ and $c$ by $a'$, then $a',b,c'$ are generators of $G_2$, and $aba^{-1}bcb^{-1}c^{-1}=1$ becomes $a'ba'^{-1}b^{-1}c'b^{-1}c'^{-1}=1$.

$G_2 \cong \langle a', b, c'\mid a'ba'^{-1}b^{-1}c'b^{-1}c'^{-1}=1\rangle \cong G_4$.

$G_1$ has abelianization $\mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ while $G_2, G_3, G_4$ have abelianization $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$,

so case 2,3,4 are equivalent and they're different from case 1.